# Access browser's page zoom controls with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to assign the **browser's** (IE/FF) **page zoom** controls (Menu: View/Zoom/Zoom In_Zoom Out) to two large "(+)(-)" icons on the web page so that vision impaired visitors can use these controls conveniently.

A lot of searching for a suitable script came up empty so here I am.

Any code you know that will do this simply?

All the best...

Bob

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to set the CSS3 `Transform` property using JavaScript to `scale` content. This won't be tied to the web browser zoom functionality though.

Comment: For example, you could set `-webkit-transform: scale(1.25);` (on a webkit browser; the equivalent in other browsers) to zoom in by 25%.

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done at all as far as I know. As has been discussed elsewhere on SO, it is possible to *detect* the browser's zoom level using a number of tricks. There's no way to *set* them from plain JavaScript.

Maybe in a Firefox extension.

Related:

- [Catch browser’s “zoom” event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)
- [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)
- [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do something similar in jQuery:

I made it up last night and tested on IE7, IE8, FF3.6, Safari 5, Chrome 10, and more.

I have a banner that overflows when people zoom out on some browsers.  So I check the width of my .nav.  If it wraps it will be shorter that its full width.

```
   $(function() {

        //launch doZoomCheck on load
        doZoomCheck();

        $(window).resize(function() {
            // .resize ALSO fires when people change the zoom of their browser.
            doZoomCheck();
        });

        function doZoomCheck() {
              var width = $(".nav ul").width();
              // if the width of the banner isn't near 976 is prolly overflowing
              if ( width > 976) {
                     // change to narrow font so menu doesn't wrap funny
                     $(".nav ul li a, #footer .frankmed").css("font-family", "Arial Narrow");
              }
                 // if width is back to normal change the font back
              if ( width < 976) {
                 // remove special styles when zoomed back out
             $(".nav ul li a").attr('style','');
             }
        }
  });
```

I'm using jQuery 1.5, prolly works back to 1.3.2 but haven't checked.

Please note: My font size is 20px already so Arial Narrow is very legible at that size.  I am not stopping the user from changing the font size.  I am not overriding it. I am just changing a font.  Do not use this script for evil.  Don't be stupid.  Accessibility is important.