# How to trigger key combo with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I have coded some stuff:

http://fincha.com/kunden/schmitt/

I zoom in with `.css("zoom")` but I need the buttons to simulate <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>

This code isn't working for me:

```
e = jQuery.Event("keydown");        
e.which = 50;       
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Please help!

EDIT

I actually wanted to `zoom-in` and `zoom-out` the whole web page, not just a input field.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery normalizes modifier keys on events by setting one or more properties on the `event` object. So, you want to set [`event.ctrlKey`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MouseEvent-ctrlKey) to `true`, so this should work for you:

```
e = jQuery.Event("keydown");        
e.which = 50;
e.ctrlKey = true;
$("input").trigger(e);
```

However, as per a comment at source (linked below):

> You cannot easily change values in the event object (probably for security reasons).

So, if you're unable to set the event's properties after constructing the `Event` object, then you can `$.extend()` it to set the `ctrlKey` property:

```
e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
fake = $.extend({}, e, {which: 50, ctrlKey: true});
$("input").trigger(fake);
```

---

One other thing: I'm not sure if you're trying to use key code `50` for the <kbd>+</kbd> or the <kbd>-</kbd> keys. Maybe you are, and you're using a different keyboard layout, but according to [this demo](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/#target), `50` is the JavaScript key code for hitting <kbd>2</kbd> - so that could also be part of your problem.

---

Source: [comments on a jQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/#comment-72949775).

---

**Edit:**

All this aside, I don't think you can *actually* change the browser's zoom level using JavaScript, even if you're "sending" the keyboard command to do so.

[Access browser's page zoom controls with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578354/access-browsers-page-zoom-controls-with-javascript)

Comment: thank you for your response, you right, there is no way to face such a hotkey

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/126/how-to-create-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-javascript/

```
var isCtrl = false;

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
}).keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 83 && isCtrl == true) {
        //run code for CTRL+S -- ie, save!
        return false;
    }
});
```

This is for Ctrl+s, but you should be able to modify it easily.

Comment: this is not what i wont. I need to simulate CTRL + by clicking on a link

Comment: Oh!  Sorry, I misunderstood the question!

Comment: I realize this wasn't a good answer for the OP, but I needed that exact solution for my own problem, so thanks!

Comment: Can't you use a `target="_blank"` then simply click it?