# Javascript send combination keystroke

Tags: javascript, keystroke

I want to send a combination keystroke to the browser using Javascript. For example, `CMD` + `A`.  I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3894552), but it doesn't seem to work. (Tested in Safari).

Comment: The example given was using `CTRL` + `KEY`, what type of keys do you mean by `CMD`?

Comment: `CMD` is probably the cmd key for a Mac

Comment: What did you expect it to do? Trigger some event handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend [mousetrap.js](http://craig.is/killing/mice). It's intuitive, lightweight and very easy to use;

Edit: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript). Note that CMD+A (or any other combination) is not really both together - it's a keydown event for both before there is a keyup for either.

Comment: I don't want to **detect** keyboard events, I want to **send** them to the browser.  mousetrap.js does look great for detecting shortcuts, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript which looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: Those examples don't show how to do a combination keystroke.