# JQuery: Focusing on HTML Select and then Triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope this isn't a duplicate because I have not seen anything that I could reference anything from but, I want to focus on the select which is just:

`$("#idHere").focus();`

I have read that you **cannot** select the options doing so but I was wondering if maybe you could `trigger()` the `spacebar` key once the `select` has been focused on?

My attempt at this was:

```
$('body').on('click', '#sid', function () {
  $("#size").attr("size", $("#size").attr("expandto")).css('z-index', 2);
  $("#size").focus().select();
  e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  fake = $.extend({}, e, { which: 32, ctrlkey: true });
  $("#size").trigger(fake);
});
```

Is this possible? But this does not work. Reference to idea: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893397/how-to-trigger-key-combo-with-jquery).

Edit: The reason I want to try trigger the `spacebar` key is because it actually acts like the enter key (or a click).

Edit to make more sense: I want to `focus()` on the `<select>` and then trigger the `spacebar` so the `<select>` is opened to display the options - all this happens within a `click` function. Is this possible?

Comment: If you set size attribute to select element, it should already be opened. In fact, i don't understand what is your issue? You should provide a sample replicating your issue, like a jsFiddle e.g

Comment: I dont think it's possible to programatically a `select` menu.

Comment: I do not have an issue and I don't want it to be constantly open, I want a button to `focus()` on the select and then (if its possible) send a key combination (spacebar). I am asking if its possible to send key combinations because if you can, a spacebar combination should open the `select` menu if its been focused on. **(in theory)** @A.Wolff

Comment: can't you just trigger() a click on the <select> to achieve what you want?

Comment: I did try that but it didn't actually work, like @tymeJV said. Which is why I am trying to figure out a way around the limitation but of course, this is all theory. Is it actually possible to send key combinations? If so, how?

Comment: No that is an exact duplicate, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank-you @A.Wolff Apologies! I did try to search for it, I'll vote close! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i was not sure this was exactly what you want :)

Comment: the wanted result was actual result of the dupe link so we can just say it is haha! Thanks though! @A.Wolff

Comment: @KyleE4K You should still test it for cross browser support. Not sure the accpeted answer will work in all cases (it didn't at time it was provided). You could still go with the hacky way like provided in my answer in dupe or better, use a custom select element instead

Comment: Yes, I altered the code but this is only a local project anyway. I appreciate the concern however! For future reference and better practice, I suppose I should cross-browser reference and debug; thanks! @A.Wolff