# How can we trigger browser's key event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Can we trigger key stroke events for of browsers like CTRL + T to open new tab,
CTRL + SHIFT + J for inspect elements , like this?

Comment: You can using jQuery, see [How to trigger key combo with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893397/how-to-trigger-key-combo-with-jquery)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you cannot do that as it would cause some major security issues.