# How to manually trigger a paste event in a text area with specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, paste

I'm trying to trigger a paste event in a `textarea` with jQuery, but this subject is quite new to me.

I've seen how one can manually trigger a keydown event simulating pressing a specific key like this:

```
var e = $.Event("keydown")
e.which = 50
$('#textarea1').trigger(e)
```

But how can I manually trigger a paste event with a provided string of text that effectively simulates a Ctrl+V or right-click > paste of a string like "Foobar"?

I have tried to simply set the value of textarea but this does not trigger a paste event.

EDIT:

I have also tried this (to simulate Ctrl+V) but no luck ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893397/how-to-trigger-key-combo-with-jquery)):

```
e = $.Event("keydown");        
e.which = 86; // 'V' key
e.ctrlKey = true;
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Comment: Can't you just set the value ?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't trigger a paste event.

Comment: @Gothdo you sure? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: If any website could fire the Paste event, any website would be able steal your Clipboard data (you may have a sensitive message or a picture in it). But for some reason, in almost all OSs, native apps are allowed to do it :(

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old question, but you were on the right track.

To manually trigger a Paste event using jQuery, you need to use the *paste* event type, e.g.:

```
const e = $.Event('paste');
$('#textarea').val('some text').trigger(e);
```

or:

```
$('#textarea').val('some text').trigger('paste');
```

Answer (score -6):

Here is a solution you can try:

```
$('body').on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: This is going to LISTEN for a paste event, will it not? I need to TRIGGER a paste event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript

Comment: Yes that link does not answer my question unfortunately. I do not need to detect Ctrl+V, I need to trigger a Ctrl+V via JavaScript.

Comment: @Submits did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Samidjo I don't fully remember what I did in the end, but I'm quite sure I came to the conclusion it wasn't possible.