# trigger ctrl+0 or control browser in 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to trigger ctrl+0 by JQ? I want to make sure every client can browse the website with 100%, I have tried `<meta viewport>`, it doesn't work:

```
<meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3894552/2815635

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work