# Zoom the page using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I wanna zoom a spesific part of my page using JQuery like browsers do. Can i do that? Should i use the coordinates of that spesific area?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578354/access-browsers-page-zoom-controls-with-javascript

Comment: use an `em` based layout; change the global font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this plugin....

[Zoom](http://mlntn.com/2008/12/11/javascript-jquery-zoom-event-plugin/)