# Zoom In/Out <body> in Jquery on .click() event, posible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

Can I get the can zoom in/out Firefox/Chrome-like effect using jQuery with no other plugin?

If so, how?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "zoom?" Are you referring to the effects of `Ctrl +` and `Ctrl -`?

Comment: This currently cannot be done. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578354/access-browsers-page-zoom-controls-with-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var currentZoom = 1;
$('button').click(function() {
    currentZoom += 0.1;
    $('body').css({
        zoom: currentZoom,
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + currentZoom + ')'
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VAvkL/).

Comment: With jquery.transform.js you can enable cross browser transform https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js