# javascript page zoom

Tags: javascript

Hi
i develop my web site
and i want to make two buttons (+ and -) with functions of ctr+ and ctr-
for zoom in and zoom out of whole web page in all browsers.
I need javascript code for this purpose
Can anybody help?

Comment: As you pointed out, browsers have this feature built in. Why do you feel the need to simulate it with a UI that users' won't be familier with?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578354/access-browsers-page-zoom-controls-with-javascript

Comment: This is client request... Not my :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you !
This will zoom the entire body tag

```js
var currentZoom = 100;
function zoom(paramvar)
{
  currentZoom += paramvar;
  document.body.style.zoom =  currentZoom + "%" 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="zoom(+10);">Zoom In</button>
<button onclick="zoom(-10);">Zoom Out</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have apply a logic to retain the current zoom size and increment/decrement parameter to find the required width. You can customize the following function as per your requirement.

```
function zoom()
{
var wdth = 1024; //Change this variable to match your configuration
document.body.style.zoom = screen.width/1024;
document.Fm.TxAre.value=1024;
alert("1024 ? : "+screen.width/1024);
}
```

This is just a quick solution. There are lot of better options available in the web. Just thought of sharing an easy method without using third party solution.

Comment: Isn't `zoom` non-standard and poorly supported?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
document.body.style.zoom
```

also in CSS :

```
element{zoom:<value>;}
```