# Javascript zoom effect?

Tags: javascript, zooming

We got this assignment from school to reproduce this example (created in Flash) into plain Javascript, HTML and CSS (jquery/Mootools not alllowed). Now i got the grid right, but i can't figure out what function to use to zoom into all the images at once? What would be a solution? One that crossed my mind is onClick every image goes in to the real size and using Javascript to disable the toolbars and then using keyarrows to navigate? Or is there a simpler way?

http://www.simpleviewer.net/postcardviewer/app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript / jquery would be best way to do so

**MojoZoom is a free JavaScript Image Zoom script** that works by moving your mouse over an image to see an zoomed version of it.

It places a square to the right of the image with the magnified portion of the image.

In addition to adding the zoom effect to your image, it will also automatically link it to its high resolution version.

The developers also released a slightly modified version of the script called MojoMagnified. Both of these are independent scripts and do not require external JS libraries to work

refer   http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/mojozoom/

also refer [5 Amazing JavaScript Image Zoom Scripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-zoom-scripts/)

Comment: Yeah, I'd figure out those plugins but yet, I don't see that working in the effect we are suppose to reproduce. It's like the whole browser focusing on one specific div.. These plugins only "zoom"/enlarge only a specific area, not the whole page. Thanks for the effort tho

Comment: @DelanodeRooij what do you want is to zoom whole web page ? its a browser by default facility

Comment: @DelanodeRooij though if you want to do it by your own refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977498/javascript-page-zoom