# Adjusting browser zoom level with Javascript

Tags: browser, zooming

In the 2-frame 'rows=' frameset I have, if a user change of the zoom level to less than the 125% value that I coded for, they will see "dead space" between the frames.

This question: [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) shows how to detect the browser's zoom level.

Is it possible to adjust the browser's zoom level using Javascript so I can keep users from changing the zoom outside of the desired levels?

Or have I simply forgotten a default coding consideration of some kind? (I've seen CSS's 'zoom' style, where presumably default zoom levels can be set.)

I am also seeing `document.body.style.zoom`, so seems we could do something like:

```
if (zoomLevelChange)
  {document.body.style.zoom= [some calculation]; }
```

Comment: Is it really possible =nobody else= has seen this?  Does no one else use a 2-frame rows frameset?

I know frameset use is frowned upon, but there is no way else to keep a top banner stationary, while changing out the bottom frame. A scrolling <div> allows the former, but not the latter.  -sk

Comment: AJAX is a more modern way that can do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)