# javascript "ctrl +" equivalent

Tags: javascript, image, browser, size, zooming

Is there some kind of javascript function that mimics the browsers <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> function? I know there is one to increase the text size but I'm looking for one that basically zooms the browser window.

Comment: See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers support a CSS `zoom` property on individual elements, beyond what is proposed in the [CSS Device Adaptation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt/) working draft.