# How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How to increase browser zoom level on page load?

here is my [web link](http://pakturkkarachiboys.org/indexa.htm) recently i got the task to increase its width just like if Firefox we press `Ctrl +` and browser zoom level is increases is there any way to do this automatically in all browsers on page load.

Comment: Note:I already googled about this not find this or something which solve this problem

Comment: If you **always** want the site to be bigger, why not style it to be bigger?

Comment: @TimMedora thanks for replying actually its required a more time to increase the size of all things and i think if i just increase zoom level so its better to add the code in pages

Comment: As a decade veteran of web development, never thought I'd want to  zoom - as it encroaches on the user's realm of control. However, for my intranet app, multiple users have their various resolutions set to work in accordance with their varying eyesight. My site scales just fine, but in some cases, is so much larger that it needs to be independently scaled back in comparison with other sites they visit. I may provide a setting they can save (persist in our db) that zooms down the site so they don't have to mess with their magnification/text size controls repeatedly every time they go to my app.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Personally I think this is a bad idea; either design your site so it scales easily (not hard with proper CSS/HTML techniques). Typically you should not make UX decisions for people.

But it is possible.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q6kebgbh/4/

```
.zoom {
    zoom: 2;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Note that previous versions of this answer used `transform` to support more browsers. However, this shortened code appears to work for current versions of Chrome, FF, Safari and IE (as well as previous versions of IE, which have supported `zoom` for a long time).

Comment: Thank you so much its working its working fine in Firefox,Chrome but not working in old internet explorer any suggestion well i am also downloading ie8

Comment: @DanishIqbal - you will need to use two different methods to support older versions of IE. I've updated my sample to show support for all browsers.

Comment: its hide all flash in this site

Comment: Here is a shorter solution? (Without all those `-nnn-transform` properties)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12603229/694469 It uses `zoom` for all browsers except for Firefox, and supposedly works in Firefox, IE8+ and Chrome.

Comment: NOTE: This is NOT actually the browser zoom. The browser zoom is still set to 100% using this technique.

Comment: Yes, agree with @cronoklee. The problem with this is that dimensions will be reported as 100% and when it is visually displayed as 200%, there could be a problem. The viewport is still 100%. When displaying a video for example, a part is below viewport and user can't press the stop button. Using the browser zoom instead, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Erwinus - yes, note that this answer is 3.5 years old and I thought it was a bad idea even then. I believe all modern browsers now support native zoom, so there is no good reason to use this approach for the overall page. Zooming a particular element still has its uses (e.g. animating the element size on mouseover).

Comment: not working for all iframes that are added by 3rd parties

Comment: Why is this a bad idea? It's a lot more helpful to say why something is bad versus just saying it is bad. All of front end dev is literally making UX decisions for people. Developers create the UX, users do not.

Comment: @ICW A better way to phrase it may be, "developers shouldn't limit legitimate, expected options available to a user." Classic example: disabling the back button because a form can't handle navigation, rather than actually fixing the form. Zooming an element might make sense in limited cases (e.g. a hover effect) but it shouldn't be the first tool used for building a responsive design. I can imagine (especially 9 1/2 years ago when I wrote this) someone trying to "fix" a site for a phone by zooming it in/out to fit.

Comment: Since the code I showed doesn't actually change the zoom level of modern browsers, it doesn't interfere with that expected user ability, so that's a good thing. But it would still be possible to interfere with a user's intentions using a little JavaScript, e.g. "my page doesn't look good zoomed in, so I'll detect layout changes and diminish the zoom property so that it looks the way I want."

Comment: This wont change the viewport zoom. Is there anyway to make the viewport to 80% zoom?

Comment: Firefox chops off the top of the page. With Chromium-based browsers, @media queries that are dependent upon viewport width don't respond.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function zoom() {
            document.body.style.zoom = "300%" 
        }
</script>

<body onload="zoom()">
<h6>content</h6>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you so much your code is working perfectly in chrome let me check in other browsers

Comment: its not working Firefox and in internet explorer it require allow script 
any suggestion

Comment: Hi Iqbal try using css body { zoom: 300%; }

Comment: css zoom its working in Chrome,Internet Explorer but not in FireFox

Comment: @DanishIqbal This answer uses `-moz-transform` instead in FireFox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12603229/694469

Comment: works in .HTA (internet explorer hypertext application)

Comment: Is there any way to change the viewport as well?

Answer (score 8):

You can try the CSS `zoom` rule. I've never really tried it, but in theory setting a css rule like the following might do what you want:

```
body { zoom: 2; }
```

Note: this doesn't actually modify the browsers zoom level. It just makes everything on the page bigger :)

Comment: @jaremysawesome thank you so mush its working in Chrome,Internet Explorer but not in Firefox any suggestion

Comment: @DanishIqbal This works with FF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12603229/694469  It uses `-moz-transform: scale(2)`.

Comment: '-moz-transform zoom' is not the same as 'zoom'. the first one breaks my complex website layout which contains fixed and absolutely positioned elements.https://www.word-party.com/

Answer (score 5):

I have PWA which has a minimalistic design with a lot of whitespace and intended for mobile phones in the first place (so initially I didn't think about big screens).

So when you open it on a very big screen (tv or large monitor) it looks really ugly (because it is too much whitespace at that point). And as a user, I need every time zoom it in. My webapp is more aesthetically pleasing as well as easier to use from a sofa on tv when it is scalled up a bit on that large screen.

*So in @media I change zoom property if a display is too wide. 
The problem is that -moz-transform: scale is absolutely different from zoom.*

Bottom line if you want to zoom website with css you have three options:

- (recommended, harder for existing page) To use **em** and **rem** units while developing your page. That will allow changing "zoom" of the page as easy as changing font size on body.
- (easier for existing page) To use "transform: scale" for cross-browser experience, but it may work not as you expected.
- (not-recommended, easy for existing page) To use CSS "zoom" property despite the fact that it is not a standard property. Sacrifices Firefox. Also, have some minor unexpected behavior with absolutely positioned flexboxes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed that when entering the zoom it was established in a defined percentage, this was useful for me

```html
<body style="zoom:90%;!important">
   <h3>Your data here!</h3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, almost browsers still block the behavior of customization the browser zoom level from code (as I read somewhere, it is stated to be a bad practice and it should be controlled by the user, not the web itself).

Although, we still can handle this by a small "*hack*", which just effect the view (look & feel), not changing the *real* browser zoom level. It may also break your layout in some situations (if responsiveness available).

In my case, I need to force the screen always in 100% (default browser zoom level) on page load, even though last time user visited the web they changed it to any other values.

I found another topic on [how to detect browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815031/12252601), combined with
[Vinod's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441615/12252601), the value of zooming (in/out) is result of `(100 / browserZoomLevel) * 100`.

```
const handleZoom = () => {
  const browserZoomLevel = Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100)
  document.body.style.zoom = `${100 / browserZoomLevel * 100}%`
}
// call handleZoom() in the place you want
```

or a shorter version

```
const handleZoom = () => {
  document.body.style.zoom = `${Math.round(100 / window.devicePixelRatio)}%`
}
```

Now pretty much browsers supports `window.devicePixelRatio`. However, the ratio maybe different on high DPI/retina displays ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815031/12252601)).

Hope this help!

I'm sorry for any inconvenience due to my English.