# Setting ie browser zoom level

Tags: browser

In ie8, I need to force browser zoom level to a specific value when my web page loads. What I need to do is not to zoom only the content, but also changing the browser zoom level as if user manually changes.

Is there a way for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wow, that's going to annoy your users! Doesn't sound like a good solution to me, can you explain a bit more about why you feel this is necessary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load