# How to trigger ctrl + and ctrl - events using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two selectors like A+ button,A- button,When I click on A+ button it should trigger the ctrl +  event. When I click on A- button it should trigger the ctrl - event.

Comment: do you want to add font resizer in jQuery.? http://www.jfontsize.com/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.ctrlKey can help you

Comment: Usage of [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) along with [`event.ctrlKey`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these in your event handlers

```
window.parent.document.body.style.zoom *=1.2//zoom in
window.parent.document.body.style.zoom *=0.8//zoom out
```

Depending on what browser you are using, transforming scale via CSS like so:

```
transform: scale(1.2);
```

may be what you are looking for.

See: 
[How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load)