# how to set the window zoom to default whenever window zooms out/ zoom level is less than 1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, webbrowser-control

please help...
I am creating a web application in which i need to set zoom level of browsers to default   when it is less than 1...
I had tried jquery resize() function that won't be helpfull to me because i m not getting how to get the window width in pixels
    any help will be appritiated... thanx...

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() { 
    if (winWidth>"1500")
    {
        //how can i pass the values again to the window width so dat it will reset to default
    }
});
```

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of the question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load).  Note the reasons listed by the highest rated answer there as to why you shouldn't be doing this for the user.

Comment: thanx 4 the help sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For chrome and above;

```
transform: scale(2); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; 
    -moz-transform: scale(2); 
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; 
    -o-transform: scale(2); 
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0; 
    -ms-transform: scale(2); 
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

IE 7 and 8

```
zoom: 2;
```

example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zgqN7/2/)