# Forcing specific zoom level for everyone

Tags: javascript, html, browser

My website relies on the user having their browser zoomed in to a specific level, but I've received comments that my site is unusable because their default zoom level is very high (mostly IE users).

How can I force a specific zoom level so that every end user will see the exact same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulate Zooming (doesn't change the browser's zoom level)

transform: scale(2);

-webkit-transform: scale(2);

-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

-moz-transform: scale(2);

-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;

-o-transform: scale(2);

-o-transform-origin: 0 0;

-ms-transform: scale(2);

-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;

Source: http://cat-in-136.blogspot.com/2010/09/unofficial-css-property-zoom.html

IE 7 and 8

zoom: 2;
These two styles may conflict, so I would suggest using a conditional comment for IE 7 and 8.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Source: [How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load)