# phantomjs fit content to A4 page

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, phantomjs

I want to convert an HTML page to an A4 sized PDF.

```
page.paperSize = {
  format: 'A4',
  orientation: 'portrait',
  border: '1cm'
};
```

Is there a way to scale the website to fit the width of A4?

If I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="width:1500px; text-align:right;">
  right 1500px
</div>
```

The right end of the div falls off the page.

I have played with the `viewportSize` property:

```
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 480,
  height: 800
};
```

I would have expected that a larger viewport width results in a a larger part of the page being rendered into the PDF.

```
page.zoom
```

Did also not have the desired effect.

The PDF files are reports. For a professional look they should be A4 and not any arbitrary size.

Or is phantomjs the wrong tool for my problem?

I am using phantomjs version 1.9.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.4.

---

**Edit:**

It seems that there are three different dimensions here:

- `vieportSize` which is the size that is used to render, as written in the docs
- `paperSize` which is the size of the resulting PDF document
- and then there is the screen size. phantomjs always fits the width of one screen on the size of the paper. The screen size of my phantomjs version is 1024 x 768 pixels. If the view port is larger than the screen size everything outside the 1024 pixels is not displayed.

I did not find a way yet to change the screen size.

I found this by rendering `http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/` to PDF.

Comment: You could manipulate the width of the element/page so that it fits into the document. The question is whether this would still look good. Which phantomjs version and which OS do you use btw?

Comment: And I would prefer to not have to design my websites around the requirements of phantomjs...

Comment: Here is another pointer: You could [simulate a page zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9441618/1816580), but this will probably break your page horribly.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to create an element that is exactly the same size as A4, and place your content in it. This worked on my machine:

```
.page{
    position:relative;
    border: 0px;
    width:calc(210mm * 1.25);
    height:calc(297mm * 1.25);
    padding:0
}
```

Note that I use a zoom factor of 1.25. This is due to [this issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12685).

Comment: This seems to work well. I do it dynamically using the "evaluate" feature and it works fine, e.g. 
document.querySelector('body').style.height = "calc(297mm * 1.25)"

Comment: i used (210 * 1.3) and it came perfect , same as firefox using zoom 130%