# Chrome and Firefox Browser Default Zoom

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem with [this page](http://www.webotronica.com). I developed it in Firefox on it's default zoom level. The idiot that I am, I haven't tested it on Chrome. So, now I see that the page's layout and/or font size is different on Chrome and other Webkit based browsers. Default Chrome zoom level is 75% so everything is smaller on Chrome. I have to say that I've made a dozen of web apps but have concentrated on the backend side of the application and never put many thoughts in how the page looks like on different browsers.

I mean, I have if javascript cross browser stuff had to be addressed but this is something that I never came across.

What I think is wrong with this is font size. I have a `#main-wrap` that wraps the entire app and has a base font size of `16px`. So, `#navigation a` has `0.7em` because that way it looks normal in Firefox, but looks really small in Chrome.

Could anyone post some tips or hints as to way this is happening?

**EDIT**:

I've fixed the problem with

```
zoom: 1.29;
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

And it works but, as I know, it's a good to do this like this. Is there a CSS technique do make pages look the same across browsers?

Comment: "Default Chrome zoom level is 75%"...no, it's not.

Comment: Oh yea, you are right. I made that assumption thinking that Firefox is at 100%. Since app looks smaller in Chrome, i thaught it's 75%. Do you know how to fix that? Maybe an article? I looked trough google but couldn't find anything or didn't look the right way

Comment: Not seeing a difference in Chrome to FF

Comment: I had to clear the cache and site preferences to Firefox and Chrome to see it.

Comment: I would have no cache on a first visit so I still cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: I don't know what to say. I called two friends who use only firefox. They installed Chrome and the see it as I see it. Also, zoom is set to default 100% in all browsers. Webkit browsers are smaller and Firefox is bigger. I don't get it. I solved it using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load but the answer says is a bad fix since the same results can be made with using proper css techniques but I don't know them

Comment: There is a setting in Chrome which allows you to set the default zoom for individual sites...

settings > Privacy > content settings > zoom levels > manage...

Just do a search in Google Chrome Settings for zoom and it's at the bottom of the content settings modal

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue as well. Using the @viewport tag works well. Here are the articles that I used to resolve the issues:

- Firefox @viewport tag - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport
- Setting viewport and zoom - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/
- To make sure fonts display weight properly across browsers, an article regarding faux font bolding is http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold

There are a lot of similar questions with suggestions. Here's one that helped me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26353104/2256476

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121839/google-chrome-and-firefox-100-zoom-scaling) is your Answers......

**For Firefox :**

1. open up a new tab, and type about:config into the address bar, and
   press enter.
2. Then use the search box, enter the word "pixel" then it will show
   "layout.css.devPixelsPerPx".
3. change the value -1.0 to 1 for 100% perfect scale...

**For Chrome:**

4. Right Click the chrome icon or chrome shortcut icon, go to the
   properties.
5. Then in the "Target:" field, Click the field and press end button.
6. Now you are seen this "chrome.exe" at the end.
7. copy this text : chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1
   /force-device-scale-factor=1

   and paste on chrome.exe"
8. Then Restart chrome or close the browser and double click the
   shortcut icon.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference is because Firefox uses the system zoomlevel. Which is set at 125% by default on Windows. Whereas Chrome uses a default level of 100%.

I would advise to design for Chrome, because then the text will always be readable.