# How to fix the Zoom problems in Google Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, updates, scaling

Latest updates of Firefox and Google Chrome affects their Default Zoom scaling. It affects Fonts size, Image size and also entire Browser.

Here is your Answers......

**For Firefox :**

1. open up a new tab, and type about:config into the address bar, and
   press enter.
2. Then use the search box, enter the word **"pixel"** then it will
       show **"layout.css.devPixelsPerPx"**.
3. **change the value -1.0 to 1** for 100% perfect scale...

**For Chrome:**

1. Right Click the chrome icon or chrome shortcut icon, go to the properties.
2. Then in the **"Target:"** field, Click the field and press end button.
3. Now you are seen this **"chrome.exe"** at the end.
4. copy this text : **chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1
   /force-device-scale-factor=1**

   and paste on **chrome.exe"**
5. Then Restart chrome or close the browser and double click the shortcut icon.