# My chrome browser is zoomed in

Tags: google-chrome

My chrome browser is zoomed in for no reason. I tried added /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1 at the end of C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe however I am getting an error saying  high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1 in the target box is not valid. Make sure the path and file name is correct.

Comment: @JaydipJ CTRL + 0 no longer works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your target is not valid, **you probably forgot the quotes** when using a path containing spaces (like program files) **and the slashes**:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1

Zooming out is just a workaround - not a solution !

I had the problem too, and I tried those solutions listed on this site:
http://techdows.com/2016/10/fix-chrome-54-looks-zoomed-in.html

However, I could not set the compatibility mode since all options are greyed out (probably company policy) and so I had to use the command line option.

Using both /high-dpi-support=1 and /force-device-scale-factor=1 did not work, my guess is that I am using a laptop and **the default DPI level is set to 125** in Windows 10. If set to 100, most programs were too small to use.

**Using only /force-device-scale-factor=1 worked for me** (keeping my 125 DPI in Windows and 100% Zoom level in Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I am also facing the same problem when updating the latest version of google chrome. Do it again because this the only solution.

Delete your old shortcut code and create latest version shortcut code. And Follow this steps.

**For Chrome:**

1. Right Click the chrome icon or chrome shortcut icon, go to the
   properties.
2. Then in the "Target:" field, Click the field and press end button.
3. Now you are seen this "chrome.exe" at the end.
4. copy this text : chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1
   /force-device-scale-factor=1 and paste on chrome.exe"
5. Then Restart chrome or close the browser and double click the
   shortcut icon.

**For Firefox:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121839/google-chrome-and-firefox-100-zoom-scaling)

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem thanks to the most recent Chrome update, tried a number of solutions but nothing worked, so looked for a way to go back to the previous version - which I have done an now everything is back to normal :)

So the insructions to roll back to a previous version can be found here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/UFSYuIr1-80

However they are a bit long winded, so here is what I did.

1. Go Chrome's file location, should be something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application.
2. Once there you should hopefully see a folder containing the previous version of Chrome - it should be something like 53.0.2785.143.
3. However, what's missing is the Chrome.exe, so we will need to get hold of this by downloading the older version of chrome again.
4. To do that you will need to go to this website http://www.chrome-portable.com/index.php/google-chrome-offline-installer and download the corrosponding installer, in my case i clicked on the link for the 53.0.2785.143 32-bit version.
5. Once it downloaded, right click on it and use WinRar (or similar) to 'extract here" - once extracted you should be left with another compressed file called "chrome". Again click on it and choose "extract here". This time you should get a file called "Chrome-bin".
6. Look inside "Chrome-bin" and you should see chrome.exe, now all you need to do is copy chrome.exe back to your older version folder (from step 2).
7. Double click on your newly copied chrome.exe and all going well Chrome should open back to how it was!
8. One final step, you will need to copy the entire 53.0.2785.143 folder to somewhere safe, other wise chrome will overwrite it again as it updates.

NOTE: So what you now have is two versions of chrome, the older version, version 53, which should look fine. And you have an the most recent version, version 54, of chrome which will continue to update etc. Any bookmarks you have will still point to the current version 54 chrome, so you will need to create new bookmarks pointing back to the old one!

Hope this helps, as I said I just followed the instructions in the link at the top of my post.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in the registry:

Add `--force-device-scale-factor=1` to the registry keys

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\chrome.exe\shell\open\command
```

Note: The first key may be reset sometimes. I assume this happens with either a Chrome or Windows update; I can't tell.

Comment: For the record, this does work; it simply appears somebody downvoted everything on this page. Haters gonna hate.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it by Holding ctrl and scrolling back

Or hold ctrl and press -

You could also change it in settings

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Click Customize and Control Google Chrome >
   Settings.
3. Click on "Show advanced settings" and scroll to the "Web
   Content" section.
4. Use the menu next to "Page Zoom" to make your
   selection:

Comment: that's not real a solution because every time I close google chrome its just zooms in again.

Comment: I changed my answer with another solution

Comment: I knew you can do that but why has it zoomed in? And when I use chrome with brackets it automatically zooms in again