# My chrome and edge browsers seems to zoom in to the site I develop using html and css. In firefox it is perfect

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, zooming, microsoft-edge, viewport

I cam across this problem when i started to design websites, they look zoomed in in chrome and edge, but it is okay in firefox.

The same websites looks perfect in my friends chrome browser. So, I must have some config settings inaccurate.

Here are some snapshots--

**Look in Firefox**--

[image: Firefox]

**Look in Chrome**--

[image: Chrome]

Look in Edge--

[image]

Here is another example--

Look in chrome--

[image: Chrome calculator]

Look in firefox--

[image: firefox calculator]

here is my display settings--

[image: display settings]

I am nt able to fgure out how to fix this, Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Link to my github repo-- [Github repo link for calculator](https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/Calculator_js)

I did not find path in while creating shorcuts as stated in one of the comments--

[image: No path edge shorcut]

Comment: I suggest trying to check the Zoom setting of the MS Edge browser and Google Chrome browser. If it is more then 100% then try to set it as 100%. Check whether it helps to fix this issue or not. Also, just for testing purposes try to set the Scale and layout display settings to 100% to check whether it makes any difference in the appearance of your site.

Comment: Also, try to post the Sample code of the site that can produce the issue on our side. It can be related to your CSS. check this thread may give you some idea about the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833004/chrome-and-firefox-browser-default-zoom?rq=1

Comment: [ https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/Calculator_js ] here is the link to my github acc. I had to set the zoom level of chrome to 75 percent. An if i set my seystem resolutioon to 100 percent then it looks okay, but other sites and the icons in my system looks odd.

Comment: Try to create a Shortcut for MS Edge and Google Chrome browser. Right-click on it and click on Properties. Go to the Shortcut tab. In the Target, field add  /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1after the path. Separate path and parameter with single space. Click on Apply and Close. Launch the browser from the shortcut and see whether it fix this issue or not.

Comment: I have updated my question, i could not find any path there in the shortcut tabs, I think this problem has to do with my systems scaling and resolution. But why others arent facing this issue. I think chrome's zoom and resolution depends on the system display settings, but firefox's is independent. But there must be some way to fix this, I can't always go and manually change the zoom to 75% for each sites i try to develop.

Comment: I mean the Edge exe path in the Target field. Add the parameter after it. See here: https://imgur.com/a/mkNDAM0

Comment: No, it did not work..

Comment: Not sure whether it is caused by any Windows OS setting or something got corrupted. Try to check for the latest Windows updates and install them. check whether it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This comment by @Deepak-MSFT fixed the issue. Votes to him on this.

> Try to create a Shortcut for MS Edge and Google Chrome browser. Right-click on it and click on Properties. Go to the Shortcut tab. In the Target, field add `/high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1` after the path. Separate path and parameter with single space. Click on Apply and Close. Launch the browser from the shortcut and see whether it fix this issue or not.

The value of the field should be something like:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-frame-rate-limit /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1`

Also work if Chrome is launched from the "Run dialog" as:

`chrome /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as you with default font size difference between Chrome and Firefox browsers and it is beacause I increased the font size in Windows 10, looks like Chrome interprets this like a general zoom increase because even the browser look is bigger now, not only the text as I intended.

Seems like a bug on Chrome side, as Firefox behaves normal and increases only the text as set in Windows.

Check the Windows font size in Settings / Ease of access / Display / Make text bigger section - there's a slider there.

My current fix is to set the default general zoom level in Chrome settings to 80%, which is a little smaller than Firefox but acceptable, probably 85% would have been perfect but I cannot set custom values.