# zoom an application to 80% by css

Tags: css, zooming, css-transforms

We are using an open source application and everything is fine about it. The only thing I dont like about the product is it's layout & text size.
If I zoom to 80% (either firefox or chrome browaer) then the application looks perfect.
As our end users are not so tech savvy, I want the application to open in 80% zoom mode.

Is there any way this can be done in css or jQuery.

I tried below

```
body {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
    zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
    zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
```

but doesn't help...it's not same as doing view -> zooms -> -- in firefox

Comment: could you please post screenshots on using browser zoom and using css? this is interesting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load)

Comment: you need to apply zoom in page level or element level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is really not possible with CSS and/or JQuery.**
Manual browser zoom and CSS **zoom** property both work differently and will produce different results.

**source:** 
[Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055365/2534513)

---

**Alternative:** On page load provide users with a modal window instructing them how to manually Zoom in/out, close it after they have zoomed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile, you may do this with a meta viewport tag.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8"/>`

However for desktops, you may have a look into this [polyfill by Nemo64](https://gist.github.com/Nemo64/dce219b81695b177000c).

```
$.cssNumber.zoom = true;
if (!("zoom" in document.body.style)) {
    $.cssHooks.zoom = {
        get: function(elem, computed, extra) {
            var value = $(elem).data('zoom');
            return value != null ? value : 1;
        },
        set: function(elem, value) {
            var $elem = $(elem);
            var size = { // without margin
                width: $elem.outerWidth(),
                height: $elem.outerWidth()
            };
            $elem.data('zoom', value);
            if (value != 1) {
                $elem.css({
                    transform: 'scale(' + value + ')',
                    marginLeft: (size.width * value - size.width) / 2,
                    marginRight: (size.width * value - size.width) / 2,
                    marginTop: (size.height * value - size.height) / 2,
                    marginBottom: (size.height * value - size.height) / 2
                });
            } else {
                $elem.css({
                    transform: null,
                    margin: null
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Once you add the polyfill you may run `$.cssHooks.zoom.set("body", 0.8);`.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but it doesnt have same effect as doing zoom -- in browser

Comment: Yes, right. I'm noticing that too. I'm trying a few other things.

Comment: Sorry, but I've not firefox to test.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using css transform?

.class{

transform : scale(0.8);

}

This can be used with in HTML conditions which detect browser types and CSS media queries.