# Browser Zoom to 75% when application loads on 1024x768

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

My application looks better when browser zoomed to 75% in IE 9.

When resolution is 1024x768 .

Can i make the IE 9 browser to zoom to 75%.

I tried with media queries.

```
@media (min-width : 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .zoo {
        transform: scale(0.75);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.75);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(0.75);
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
}
```

Added this css class to body.But it dosen't work

Answer (score 0):

So you want to apply manual browser zooming using CSS and/or JS?

> This is really not possible with CSS and/or JQuery. Manual browser
>   zoom and CSS zoom property both work differently and will produce
>   different results.

---

> Alternative: On page load provide users with a modal window
>   instructing them how to manually Zoom in/out, close it after they have
>   zoomed successfully.

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30152402/2534513

[Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055365/2534513)

Comment: body {  
 
  font-size: 12px !important;
 transform : scale(0.8);
 -ms-transform:: scale(0.8);
}                                             this works for google chrome, but not working in IE9

Comment: That is actually css scaling, different from browser zoom. As you add more elements to your page the difference between the two will be more evident. IE will continue to struggle.