# How to Increase browser zoom level on fullscreen HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, zooming

Is it possible to increase browser zoom level? when full screen on HTML5 video?

I want to set it to 125% instead of 100% (default).

Hint:[How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load)