# IE11 display website at different zoom levels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

My web application has strange display issues when I test it in IE 11 on a window 7 machine. It displays the website at different zoom levels when it is loaded, like 125%, 100% or 90%, 80%, etc., but I want it to be always 100%. It works fine in other browsers I've tested with. 
Although the user can manually change the zoom level, but I wanna see if anyone has experienced it and if there is a possible fix.

I am using Bootstrap, and I have included this in the head:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript on page load like this:

```
document.body.style.zoom="100%"
```

Or with css like this:

```
body{zoom: 100%;}
```

Comment: Tried it. Still broken :(

Comment: @Glenna then can you provide more detail to your question?