# How to change zoom property by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, zooming

Is there a chance to change zoom value by JS. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
document.getElementsById("div").style.zoom="150%";
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `getElementsById`?

Comment: The best way is to do that is doing this.<br />
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9441618/7349445

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the zoom property is, but if you want to zoom in a `<div>`, you should use the css `transform:scale(x)` property, but you could set this property via js like this:

```
document.getElementsById("elementId").style.transform ="scale(1.5)";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/og2tqez3/

you can change the `1.5` value to the amount you want to zoom by, 1.5 means 150%, etc... 
however be careful when setting this property with js, because you literally overwrite any other transforms on that element, in that case you should set the old transform value and the zoom value and seperate them with spaces like this:

```
document.getElementsById("elementId").style.transform ="scale(1.5) transform:translate(0,-50%)";
```

My bad, so i now know what the `zoom` property is, but `scale` is more widely supported and optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found solution. I changed the class.

```
document.getElementById(div).className = "class";
```