# Open webpage from a bookmark using preset zoom level

Tags: javascript

I'm vision impaired. This is not usually a problem but some webpages that are in my Firefox bookmarks (lets say, `http://www.example.com`) use a very small font. As a consequence, I usually open the page and then use CTRL-+ to increase the zoom level.

Is it possible to open `http://example.com` programmatically with a preset zoom level? I have not been able to find any similar question, perhaps because of not stumbling on the correct search terms!

Comment: you can add an extension like greasemonkey for firefox where you set custom user scripts to be injected onload these could according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load increase the zoom level

Comment: an actual script could look something like `onload=()=>document.body.style.zoom=2` this however does not use the inbuilt zooming like in firefox so you should also add osme keylisteners to be able to reset it