# CSS zoom/transform behavior in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zooming

I want to show the screen in "100%" size in IE with CSS.
The default zoom size for IE *for my clients' computer* is 150%.
To show the screen properly **without asking my clients to change the default zoom setting**, I thought I can set the css 67%.(150% x 67% = 100.5%)

I have tried both "zoom : 67%" and "transform : scale(67%)", but neither of them worked properly.

Does anybody have idea how to fix the problem with CSS?

"The easiest way to fix would be *NOT writing any CSS* and *Asking my client to see the page with 100%*"... hope somebody can solve this.
I have tried the width: 1920px, and it also didn't work.

Hope the code below helps. I am currently using lowcode platform Mendix and customizing the given layouts.

```
.layout-atlas-responsive-default {
$sidebar-width: 60px;
zoom: 67%;

//.mx-placeholder seems to decide the width
//.mx-placeholder{
//width: 1920px;

@media (min-width: $screen-md) {
    .mx-scrollcontainer:not(.mx-scrollcontainer-open) > .region-sidebar {
        width: $sidebar-width!important;

        .mx-scrollcontainer-wrapper > .mx-navigationtree ul li {
            &.mx-navigationtree-has-items:hover {
                a {
                    background-color: $navsidebar-sub-bg;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    color: white;
                }

                a:hover{
```

[IE default zoom(sorry it's in Japanese, but hope you understand what I meant)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPLp7.png)

[CSS 67% zoom with default IE screen (150%)/ The Screen I got :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQsNX.png)

[no CSS zoom with IE screen(100%)/ The screen I want :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ6PG.png)

[CSS 100% zoom with default IE screen (150%) / The screen I want to change from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL2U8.png)
When I changed the IE screen zoom to 100%, it looked properly.

[set the width: 1920px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3OEE.png)

Comment: Do you mean that your app looks smaller even though the zoom has set to 150% and you want to display it properly by covering the whole screen? If not, please provide more information about it. I suggest please share the sample code that we can use to reproduce the issue with the IE 11 browser. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I want any CSS function that have same behavior with "Ctrl + " "Ctrl - " for IE. I have updated the question, I hope the new explanation helps.

Comment: did you try to make a test with the `zoom:100%`? did it work? What result did it give you?

Comment: It gave me the same result as "no CSS zoom".  But since the default zoom size is 150%, the screen is quite large. I have updated the image as well.

Comment: I suggest you make a test with the sample code suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441618/10309381). See whether it helps to display the site properly.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried the code, unfortunately, it gave me the same look as the [second capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQsNX.png)

Comment: In that case, I suggest you try to modify the code of the site and try to make it responsive so that it can scale it as per the screen size and it gets a display properly.

Comment: Thank you Deepak, sorry I don't get that yet.. Do you mean I should change '@media (min-width: $screen-md) ' part? Not the 'zoom' 'transform : scale'?

Comment: What I mean is try to write your media queries properly so that the web page adjusts itself according to different screen size and get display properly.