# How to change DPI (or how to zoom) for the whole react app?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a web design, that is drawn for 1920 x 1080 pixels. It looks good on such screen resolution, however, it looks worse if open on smaller screen. The acceptable look can be achieved if use native browser 'ctrl +', 'ctrl -' zooming. I'd like to do the next:

1. on page load grab the browser vieport width
2. calculate desired zoom level
3. apply zoom

is it possible with html/css/js? Does someone solve similar problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Increase browser zoom level on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441557/how-to-increase-browser-zoom-level-on-page-load)

Comment: @Nicolapps thank you, it's good idea, but required changes to styles, because css Zoom change only sizes of Page, but the size of the viewport will be untouched, as difference between css and browser does. it means that 100vh or 100% will be broken with css Zoom.