# set default zoom level for entire website

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a website, which is built with Blazor server.
in there it has components with datagrid, tables, etc.

hwoever the website looks great in 90% zoom level from the browser, but I don't want to isntruct all users to change the zoom level from default 100% to 90%. is there a way to accomplish this via code?

I have tried the

```
.zoomed-element {
    zoom: 1.8;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

but it looks I'm doing it wrong as I've tried to add the class wrapping the _Layout but I only get to reduce the size of the element, but they don't use the entire screen now, (is like a viewport)

Comment: If it looks right at 90%, then you should style everything to _that_ size instead of whatever you're using now.

Comment: Have you tried with `javascript`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74821356/1807452 ?