# Extjs 3.4 default zoom in value

Tags: extjs3

Help me in setting the default zoom in size  for the extjs page using extjs3.4

Answer (score 1):

There is no zoom option in ExtJS 3.4 and there is no javascript crossbrowser zoom option yet. But it could be achieved by CSS3.

see:
[Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)