# Globally Adjust XULRunner Font Size

Tags: xul, xulrunner

In firefox Ctrl-Plus and Ctrl-Minus adjust font size.  I would like to implement something similar in my xulrunner app.  Mostly I want to control the font size of the XUL windows.  It might also be useful to also control the font size of iframe elements that contain HTML.  Is there an API or preference to do this.  Or is there a way to rewrite a CSS file and then tell all windows to reread the CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063228/programmatically-zoom-out-web-page

Comment: See CSS transform https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform