# Restoring page zoom/scale via button

Tags: javascript, html

Unfortunately I have no code at all to begin with. After a long search on Google and on Stackoverflow I can't seem to find anything related with this.

Basically I have a button on my webpage saying, for example, "Restore scale", so that when someone clicks on it, the page's zoom/scale restores to 100%. Though I have no clue about how to do this.

Can someone help?

Comment: First result in google search... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level

Comment: I dont think this is possible.

Comment: [http://www.google.com/search?q=html+button+zoom+page](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+button+zoom+page)

Comment: try http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Zooming-a-web-page-using-Javascript-functions-335.php

Answer (score 0):

JQuery and CSS sollution:

```
$('body').css('MozTransform','scale(1)');
```

Comment: This only resizes the body, not really the page by the browser's API. It's useful but not what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing body with html