# Compensate for browser zoom in Three.js CSSRenderer

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, three.js

I'm working on a project in three.js using the CSSRenderer and I've been told that I need to make it display properly when the browser's zoom is not 100%.  From what I can tell:

- There's no way to force the browser to go back to 100%
- There's no way to detect what zoom the browser is at (according to https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom)

I thought maybe if I could detect the zoom I could do a css zoom in the other direction to compensate, kindof like it was suggested in Vijey's post here: [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)

Given this, it seems impossible to display the three.js scene properly on non- 100% zoom, and I couldn't even display a warning telling the user the app will not work properly with the browser zoom scaled.  Can someone prove me wrong on this ?  Does anyone know if there's anything being done to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Three.js applies transformations using the matrix3d() function. There is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242685) with Chrome whereby 3d transformations using matrix3D do not scale correctly under browser zoom.

You can see an example of the bug [here](http://www.mark-lundin.com/css3dbug/zoom-bug.html). If you change the zoom level you'll notice the boundary between the red and blue boxes changes.

The solution is to apply the transformation using the rotate, translate and scale transformations independently. This method avoids the Chrome bug and scales as [expected](http://www.mark-lundin.com/css3dbug/zoom-fix.html) (boundary between boxes is consistent across zoom levels).

Here is an updated [CSSRenderer](https://gist.github.com/marklundin/9620459#file-gistfile1-txt-L124) that uses this technique and scales correctly.