# Need to change browser zoom level for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, zooming

Please consider this scenario. I have set my IE zoom level to 125% or 150%. When I click a link on my page(zoomed to 125% or 150%) it opens a new window.

My questions is can I reset the zoom level of the new window back to 100% regardless at what zoom value I have launched the window from.

I have already tried using document.body.style.zoom, it sort of does the purpose but it reduces the overall sizeof my web page content. I want my content to look like it will look @ zoom of 100%.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level