# Force browser Zoom level when my website opens

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reasons, I have a website that need to zoomed-out by some web browsers.
I have our company's Logo as the Background of the site and make all the things with `position:fixed;` in css. So I need the browser to zoom out a bit to about 80% or 70%. By the way, if you can help me with this website to make it responsive, you make me very happy. Because as far as i know, if I make this website responsive all contents will crash and go inside each other, because i use Our Company Logo as the background and the base of the site and design the site on it ( buttons, boxes and etc. are all in Fixed Positions ).

Comment: Why have you used position fixed for all the **things** `"elements"`? Use a standard relative position and percentage widths.

Comment: because all the contents should be on my Logo , i cant use relative , because all the contents will get inside each other JUST because of the logo as background and all the content should fix the Logo , not their own positions . its not a normal website . its fully unique

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)

Answer (score 0):

[Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)

This isn't a practice that you should use. Either scale up your graphics or try again using relative positioning.