# onclick zoom window using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons(Zoom in and Zoom out). If I click the zoom in button the window will zoom in 10%, when I click the zoom out button it should Zoom out 10%. How can I achieve this??

Comment: You cannot change the browser zoom, so you'll have to create a javascript solution. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level for ideas

Comment: U can try with an iframe and use this plugin https://github.com/HubSpot/jquery-zoomer

Comment: If you set the size of everything using EM then you can change the EM of the body element and it'll "zoom" everything else.