# Zoom a browser with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, meta

I'm curious if there's any way to force a window zoom or change the reference pixel size. I know you can get a reported zoom level with `window.devicePixelRatio`

We've been using `rem` and changing the root html `font-size`, but want to use pixels, since DPI and accessibility are compensated for by the browser's reference pixel, and most measurements like `clientWidth` and drag touch events are measured in `px` and we're using additional math to just scale it into `rem` for no reason!

Thanks

Comment: You can zoom the page like this `document.body.style.zoom = 1.2` keep chaging 1.2 to 1.3, 1.4 etc.., Not sure if it gets your desired results

Comment: 1 comment; transform is [completely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)(at least in main browsers, blah, blah, blah), and it includes a scale option. Use it as you may.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the browser zoom level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)

Answer (score 1):

I've used zoom-in using Javascript. I'm simply using `document.body.style.zoom=1.5;`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/duu72wsw/) is a fiddle you can see. Perhaps this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The css `zoom` attribute is **not** [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom), but transform is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), though it is probably still better to use a library, `transform: scale(%);` is the easiest way.

```css
p {
  animation: scale 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>I'll grow larger and smaller<p>
```