# How to control ctrl + and ctrl - browser zoom level using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

any other option other than zoom property and transform-scale property ?
Only using JavaScript or jQuery .

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`document.body.style.zoom = 2.0;`

However it is not supported in every browser:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom