# Browser Zoom level

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I know this post already exist but no one answer correctly.
I want to know how to change the browser zoom in JS

My first page : I zoom to 150% with ctrl +

I want to go to my second page : I click on a button 'second page'.
After this I have the 150% in my second page, how can I modify or set to default 100% my  second page.

What I know : 
ZOOM propriety css is not what I want, it's the browser(opera,chrome,mozilla), same for scale propriety.
AccessKey permit to keypress on the keyboard but I want to click or touch to do the opposite like one click = ctrl +.

Thanks you
MT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)

Comment: As i said before no one correctly answer about this issue.