# Chrome browser defaults Zoom to 80% on site load

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am facing an issue with Chrome where my site is being zoomed out from **100%** to **80%** automatically. I know that **browsers cache** the zoom settings based on domain and set it when the users loads it next time. But I haven't done anything like that as am opening the site for the first time. I am unable to find the root cause for this issue.

**Example** : I have 5 portals and each have a different domain address, when I continue navigating back and forth between the portals, one of the portals zooms out to 80% while the rest remain at 100%.

Is there a way that I can prevent this behavior in desktops ?

**Note** : I have checked my css properties and I haven't used zoom properties.

Comment: @Novice: from your question I understood that, when you open one of the site url it is automatically zooming to 80% when you navigating between 5 sites, is same thing happening when you open that particular  site first time? have you tested  in other browsers? also share that site url so that I can also test my self

Comment: The site is still in its dev phase, so its not out for public access yet. It happens for the first time. I have tested it in firefox but I could't reproduce it. @SreehariBallampalli

Answer (score 0):

Have you set all your ports to default zoom yet?(100%)
Try it on another computer or another browser to be sure of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here there are many solution, I hanven't try it but you can try

[Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)

these solutions are with buttons, but you can try to take the idea and customize it for you problem