# How can I zoom html upon button click?

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I am trying to provide a function on an html page with which I can zoom in and out text.

I already tried with all available browsers. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        #zoomtext
        {
            transform: scale(1);
            transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function()
        {
            var zoom = 1;
            var zoomStep = 0.2;
        });
        document.getElementById("zoomIn").addEventListener("click",function(){zoom += zoomStep; document.getElementById("zoomtext").style.transform = "scale("+zoom+")";});
        document.getElementById("zoomOut").addEventListener("click",function(){if(zoom > zoomStep){zoom -= zoomStep; document.getElementById("zoomtext").style.transform = "scale("+zoom+")";}});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="zoomOut">-</button>
        <button id="zoomIn">+</button>
        <article>
            <section id="zoomtext">
                <p>This is a text that I want to be able to zoom in and out by means of the two buttons indicating plus and minus.</p>
            </section>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is no error message. Nothing happens upon click.

Comment: you either need to run the script on document ready, or after you add the html to the page - at the moment the buttons do not exist when you do your getelementbyid as you are just running the script in the header

Answer (score 2):

- Add `script` at end of `body`
- Assign `zoom, zoomStep` variables outside eventlistener callback

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #zoomtext {
      transform: scale(1);
      transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="zoomOut">-</button>
  <button id="zoomIn">+</button>
  <article>
    <section id="zoomtext">
      <p>This is a text that I want to be able to zoom in and out by means of the two buttons indicating plus and minus.</p>
    </section>
  </article>

  <script>
    var zoom = 1;
    var zoomStep = 0.2;

    document.getElementById("zoomIn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      zoom += zoomStep;
      document.getElementById("zoomtext").style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")";
    });
    document.getElementById("zoomOut").addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (zoom > zoomStep) {
        zoom -= zoomStep;
        document.getElementById("zoomtext").style.transform = "scale(" + zoom + ")";
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that `zoom` and `zoomStep` are never evaluated. The first event listener just create a function, but the code inside it is never executed.

See a working code here : https://codepen.io/marc-simplon/pen/vqYwYQ?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set the zoom of the whole window, that might not be possible without an external plugin (see [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level))

If you want to set the zoom for specifically the #zoomtext element, you could use the "zoom" CSS attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom), but it is not standard. Another way of handling this would be to increase or decrease the font-size CSS attribute on the #zoomtext element:

```
document.getElementById("zoomtext").style.fontSize = '12px'
```