# how to set zoom in browser?

Tags: html, css

Um yes, I was just wondering if it was javascript or css and what is the syntax? Thank you

Comment: I removed the sql tag, since this is clearly unrelated.

Comment: Can you imagine how much of a user experience nightmare it would be if websites could set the user's zoom level?

Comment: Duplicate of [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)