# How can i navigate a iframe or div using arrows (buttons) and zoom in and out like google docs but for html page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a bracket generated with javascript i want the preview of the bracket to be in a iframe or any thing else , just in smthg that im able to navigate through the bracket and i can zoom in and this stuff , is there any library can help or templates ? [example in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxtou.jpg)

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: the code is a normal html page , i just want to emmbed it in a iframe like that one in the pic ...

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level

Do you want to zoom in on just the iframe, or on the entire site?

Comment: just the iframe ..