# Changing scale of all items on webpage

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, zooming

I have just finished my project, but after finishing I realized that my localhost:3000 is zoomed in to 125%, so at 100% my project looks less than ideal.

Is there a way to change the zoom/scale of my website to reflect what I looked like on my localhost? I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level) that deals with browser zoom, however when I tried to set:

```
function toggleZoomScreen() {
        document.body.style.zoom = "125%";  //my zoom was at 125%
    }
```

It seemed to simply zoom in the view of the webpage like a camera, example here. I'm also not sure why it seemed to shift the webpage to the right.

[image: document.zoom.125]

and by comparison, here's what it looks like when I have my browser zoom set at 125%

[image: browserzoom 125]

Can I fix this without having to redo the css on the entire website?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your main css file

```
body{
   overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

This will avoid the webpage shifting right or basically getting overflowed !

Comment: Actually the solution to this was to use `rem`, `em`, and `%` instead of `px`.