# Is there a way to change default zoom of my website using HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css

I made a website according to my browser setting which was 50% zoom, now whenever anyone is opening my webpage in their browser it is showing as too zoomed as their browser default zoom is 100%. How can I resolve this issue.

I tried using *{zoom:50%} in CSS so set default zoom of the website as 50% but it didi not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the browser zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055336/changing-the-browser-zoom-level)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `*` try on the `body`

```css
body {
  zoom: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I tried but then it was then zoomed out too much

Comment: `zoom` doesn't work on FIrefox.